# How can show current_user's friends' posts and what's popular in one record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scopes

I have set up my scopes and all are working as expected but I could find a way to filter the friends posts in one scope.
In the model

```
scope :popular, ->{ where("cached_votes_up > '20'") } # change this to a much bigger number overtime
scope :following, ->{ where(Post.current_user.following.ids.include? user_id) }
scope :ordered, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

In the controller

```
@post = Post.ordered.popular.following.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => 1)
```

How can I add the following/friend filtering for a scope so i can merge them with other scopes.

I'm trying to make the page display posts with more than 20 likes and also display friends' posts even if they're not above 20.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
include PublicActivity::Common
cattr_accessor :current_usercontroller.current_user}
scope :popular, ->{ where("cached_votes_up > '1'") } # change this to a much bigger number overtimeuser_id) }
scope :ordered, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
acts_as_votable
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "550", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :image, presence: true
default_scope { order("created_at DESC")}
has_many :comments
is_impressionable # :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :my_column_name, :unique => true
  def previous_post
    self.class.where("created_at < ?", created_at).order(created_at: :desc).first
  end

  def next_post
    self.class.where("created_at > ?", created_at).order(created_at: :asc).last
  end
```

end

and relationships.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
validates :follower_id, presence: true
validates :followed_id, presence: true
```

end

and the user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  include PublicActivity::Common
  acts_as_voter
  is_impressionable
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "missing.jpg"
  has_attached_file :cover, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "missing.jpg"
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :active_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :comments
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates_attachment :image, :cover,
                     content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }

  def follow(other)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other.id)
  end

  def unfollow(other)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other.id).destroy
  end

  def following?(other)
    following.include?(other)
  end  

end
```

Comment: Please share both related models as well.

Comment: what is the result of the merging?

Comment: Just added all the models, the results are working but without .following, it's returning an error on user_id for Class post. I think this shouldn't be solved in the model .